# How to add new entries to string array in android/java?

Tags: java, android

```
String newwords="hi pls solve this";

mStrings[]= {"abc","def","ghi"};
mStrings = mStrings+newwords.split(" "); //wrong
```

I know this code is wrong, but am expecting content in mStrings as `{"abc","def","ghi","hi","pls","solve","this"}`.
Is there any operation to make  this?

Thanks.

Comment: where in code you attempted to add element ?

Comment: am indicated that as wrong. in my code. sorry am a beginner.

Comment: use arraylist for further adding the data in array

Answer (score 2):

Use `StringTokenizer` class to split the string into words/tokens and then add each of them to an `ArrayList`. You cannot increase/decrease the size of array and so you need to use `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the size of an array in Java, if you need to do this, either you need to allocate a new array, move over the old values, then add the new ones OR you need to use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi) for this. I tried your problem and got the result as you asked for. Heres the code:

```
public class JavaTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String newwords = "hi pls solve this";
    String mStrings[] = { "abc", "def", "ghi" };
    String[] msStrings = ArrayUtils.addAll(mStrings, newwords.split(" "));
    for (String s : msStrings) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
}
```